# Xorg uses too much memory in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, xorg, memory-usage

After a few minutes of working with [Blender](https://www.blender.org) 2.82 I noticed high memory usage (i.e almost 4GBs which is 1/4 of my RAM) from `Xorg` process in my system.After closing the blender though, the situation didn't change at all.
I currently use Kubuntu 20.04 and I've seen similar problem in `Ubuntu studio 19.04` again with blender.
Have somebody seen a similar problem with other programs or is it perhaps a bug in the blender itself?
I use Nvidia GeForce GT 740 with driver 440 installed.

Thanks.